# Excluding several layers from forEachFeatureAtPixel function using OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

I have a map with some vector layers that deliver popups when the user clicks on the markers. I use a forEachFeatureAtPixel function to identify these layers. However, there are also several background layers which should do nothing if you click on them. After looking through this forum for methods, I am able to exclude one layer from the function, but how would I exclude several layers?

Background1 and background2 are the layers that should not deliver any popups. My code is like this:

```
var background1 = new ol.layer.Vector...

var background2 = new ol.layer.Vector...

var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
if (layer != background1) return feature;
});

if (feature) {

//etc.
```

That works fine, but I also want to exclude background2. I thought I could write "if (layer != background1 || background2) return feature;" but that doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Why `||` and not `&&`. I mean in terms of logic you want to exclude these two layers, right?. If yes, It should be `if (layer != background1 && layer != background2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (layer != background1 && layer != background2)`

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.